# Rounded LinearProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a rounded tail of the `LinearProgressIndicator`.

[image]

Is it possible without replacing the `drawBar` implementation in `progress_indicator.dart`? I don't want to copy all the existing code as it means a lot of maintenance.

```
void drawBar(double x, double width) {

  if (width <= 0.0)
    return;

  double left;
  switch (textDirection) {
    case TextDirection.rtl:
      left = size.width - width - x;
      break;
    case TextDirection.ltr:
      left = x;
      break;
  }
  canvas.drawRect(Offset(left, 0.0) & Size(width, size.height), paint);
}
```

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130073/rounded-linearprogressindicator-in-flutter/76716089#76716089

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's no way without implementing it myself. I'm using the [percent_indicator package](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) now.