# Rounded LinearProgressIndicator in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to take a `LinearProgressIndicator()` component in flutter and have all the edges be rounded instead of square without using any libraries?

Answer (score 16):

You need to wrap it with `ClipRRect`

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
    child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
  )
```

[ClipRRect class documentation on flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `LinearProgressIndicator` in a `Container` and give it `RoundedRectangleborder`. Like this,

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
  ),
  ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  height: 5,
  child: const LinearProgressIndicator(
     value: 0.34,
     color: Colors.green,
     backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
  ),
)
```

It'll give it rounded edges.

Answer (score -1):

I know you said without libraries, but you could try my library ([capped_progress_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/capped_progress_indicator)) that does what you want and works exactly like Flutter's original `LinearProgressIndicator` and `CircularProgressIndicator`. It not only rounds the ends of the track/background but also the ends of the progress/indicator.

So its just a matter of installing the package and changing your code from

```dart
LinearProgressIndicator(
  // ...
)
```

to

```dart
import 'package:capped_progress_indicator/capped_progress_indicator.dart';

LinearCappedProgressIndicator(
  // ...
)
```

You can also change the corner radius to your liking

```dart
LinearCappedProgressIndicator(), // Circle end (default).
LinearCappedProgressIndicator(cornerRadius: 5), // Rounded end.
LinearCappedProgressIndicator(cornerRadius: 0), // Square end.
```